# Spurious underflow in C++ lock-free queue implementation

Tags: c++, lock-free

I'm trying to implement a lock-free queue that uses a linear circular buffer to store data. In contrast to a general-purpose lock-free queue I have the following relaxing conditions:

- **I know the worst-case number of elements that will ever be stored in the queue.** The queue is part of a system that operates on a fixed set of elements. The code will never attempt to store more elements in the queue as there are elements in this fixed set.
- **No multi-producer/multi-consumer.** The queue will either be used in a multi-producer/single-consumer *or* a single-producer/multi-consumer setting.

Conceptually, the queue is implemented as follows

- **Standard power-of-two ring buffer.** The underlying data-structure is a standard ring-buffer using the [power-of-two trick](https://www.snellman.net/blog/archive/2016-12-13-ring-buffers/). Read and write indices are only ever incremented. They are clamped to the size of the underlying array when indexing into the array using a simple bitmask. The read pointer is atomically incremented in `pop()`, the write pointer is atomically incremented in `push()`.
- **Size variable gates access to `pop()`.** An additional "size" variable tracks the number of elements in the queue. This eliminates the need to perform arithmetic on the read and write indices. The size variable is atomically incremented after the entire write operation has taken place, i.e. the data has been written to the backing storage *and* the write cursor has been incremented. I'm using a [compare-and-swap (CAS)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) operation to atomically decrement size in `pop()` and only continue, if size is non-zero. This way `pop()` should be guaranteed to return valid data.

My queue implementation is as follows. Note the debug code that halts execution whenever `pop()` attempts to read past the memory that has previously been written by `push()`. This should never happen, since ‒ at least conceptually ‒ `pop()` may only proceed if there are elements on the queue (there should be no underflows).

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>
#include <csignal> // XXX for debugging

template <typename T>
class Queue {
private:
    uint32_t m_data_size;   // Number of elements allocated
    std::atomic<T> *m_data; // Queue data, size is power of two
    uint32_t m_mask;        // Bitwise AND mask for m_rd_ptr and m_wr_ptr
    std::atomic<uint32_t> m_rd_ptr; // Circular buffer read pointer
    std::atomic<uint32_t> m_wr_ptr; // Circular buffer write pointer
    std::atomic<uint32_t> m_size;   // Number of elements in the queue

    static uint32_t upper_power_of_two(uint32_t v) {
        v--; // https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html
        v |= v >> 1; v |= v >> 2; v |= v >> 4; v |= v >> 8; v |= v >> 16;
        v++;
        return v;
    }

public:
    struct Optional { // Minimal replacement for std::optional
        bool good;
        T value;
        Optional() : good(false) {}
        Optional(T value) : good(true), value(std::move(value)) {}
        explicit operator bool() const { return good; }
    };

    Queue(uint32_t max_size)
        : // XXX Allocate 1 MiB of additional memory for debugging purposes
          m_data_size(upper_power_of_two(1024 * 1024 + max_size)),
          m_data(new std::atomic<T>[m_data_size]),
          m_mask(m_data_size - 1),
          m_rd_ptr(0),
          m_wr_ptr(0),
          m_size(0) {
        // XXX Debug code begin
        // Fill the memory with a marker so we can detect invalid reads
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < m_data_size; i++) {
            m_data[i] = 0xDEADBEAF;
        }
        // XXX Debug code end
    }

    ~Queue() { delete[] m_data; }

    Optional pop() {
        // Atomically decrement the size variable
        uint32_t size = m_size.load();
        while (size != 0 && !m_size.compare_exchange_weak(size, size - 1)) {
        }

        // The queue is empty, abort
        if (size <= 0) {
            return Optional();
        }

        // Read the actual element, atomically increase the read pointer
        T res = m_data[(m_rd_ptr++) & m_mask].load();

        // XXX Debug code begin
        if (res == T(0xDEADBEAF)) {
            std::raise(SIGTRAP);
        }
        // XXX Debug code end
        return res;
    }

    void push(T t) {
        m_data[(m_wr_ptr++) & m_mask].store(t);
        m_size++;
    }

    bool empty() const { return m_size == 0; }
};
```

However, underflows do occur and can easily be triggered in a multi-threaded stress-test. In this particular test I maintain two queues `q1` and `q2`. In the main thread I feed a fixed number of elements into `q1`. Two worker threads read from `q1` and push onto `q2` in a tight loop. The main thread reads data from `q2` and feeds it back to `q1`.

This works fine if there is only one worker-thread (single-producer/single-consumer) or as long as all worker-threads are on the same CPU as the main thread.  However, it fails as soon as there are two worker threads that are explicitly scheduled onto a different CPU than the main thread.

The following code implements this test

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

static void queue_stress_test_main(std::atomic<uint32_t> &done_count,
                                   Queue<int> &queue_rd, Queue<int> &queue_wr) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (1UL << 24); i++) {
        auto res = queue_rd.pop();
        if (res) {
            queue_wr.push(res.value);
        }
    }
    done_count++;
}

static void set_thread_affinity(pthread_t thread, int cpu) {
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(cpu, &cpuset);
    if (pthread_setaffinity_np(thread, sizeof(cpu_set_t),
                               &cpuset) != 0) {
        throw "Error while calling pthread_setaffinity_np";
    }
}

int main() {
    static constexpr uint32_t n_threads{2U}; // Number of worker threads
    //static constexpr uint32_t n_threads{1U}; // < Works fine
    static constexpr uint32_t max_size{16U}; // Elements in the queue
    std::atomic<uint32_t> done_count{0};     // Number of finished threads
    Queue<int> queue1(max_size), queue2(max_size);

    // Launch n_threads threads, make sure the main thread and the two worker
    // threads are on different CPUs.
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n_threads; i++) {
        threads.emplace_back(queue_stress_test_main, std::ref(done_count),
                             std::ref(queue1), std::ref(queue2));
        set_thread_affinity(threads.back().native_handle(), 0);
    }
    set_thread_affinity(pthread_self(), 1);
    //set_thread_affinity(pthread_self(), 0); // < Works fine

    // Pump data from queue2 into queue1
    uint32_t elems_written = 0;
    while (done_count < n_threads || !queue2.empty()) {
        // Initially fill queue1 with all values from 0..max_size-1
        if (elems_written < max_size) {
            queue1.push(elems_written++);
        }

        // Read elements from queue2 and put them into queue1
        auto res = queue2.pop();
        if (res) {
            queue1.push(res.value);
        }
    }

    // Wait for all threads to finish
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n_threads; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
}
```

Most of the time this program triggers the trap in the queue code, which means that `pop()` attempts to read memory that has never been touched by `push()` ‒ although `pop()` *should* only succeed if `push()` has been called at least as often as `pop()`.

You can compile and run the above program with GCC/clang on Linux using

```
c++ -std=c++11 queue.cpp -o queue -lpthread && ./queue
```

Either just concatenate the above two code blocks or download the complete program [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/astoeckel/1e5e7cc7a97ea177dcd16daa0abba675/raw/5dc29dc1f986a2bd948b333451432783d9006bc7/queue.cpp).

Note that I'm a complete novice when it comes to lock-free datastructures. I'm perfectly aware that there are plenty of battle-tested lock-free queue implementations for C++. However, I simply can't figure out why the above code does not work as intended.

Comment: could not reproduce your problem :https://repl.it/repls/FlashyMediocreDebuggers

Comment: @Kapil: Thanks for trying this out! Although (as pointed out in the comments below) the algorithm is fundamentally flawed, this will only fail with a high probability on a decently fast SMP machine. It is better to try this algorithm without any virtualisation in an execution environment you have full control over. Plus, putting a print statement in the thread is bad idea, since the loop has to be as tight as possible to increase the chance of triggering the concurrency issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two bugs, one of which can cause the failure you observe.

Let's look at your push code, except we'll allow only one operation per statement:

```
void push(T t)
{
    auto const claimed_index = m_wr_ptr++;               /* 1 */
    auto const claimed_offset = claimed_index & m_mask; /* 2 */
    auto& claimed_data = m_data[claimed_offset];         /* 3 */
    claimed_data.store(t);                               /* 4 */
    m_size++;                                            /* 5 */
}
```

Now, for a queue with two producers, there is a window of vulnerability to a race condition between operations 1 and 4:

Before:

```
m_rd_ptr == 1
m_wr_ptr == 1
m_size == 0
```

Producer A:

```
/* 1 */ claimed_index = 1; m_wr_ptr = 2;
/* 2 */ claimed_offset = 1;
```

- Scheduler puts Producer A to sleep here

Producer B:

```
/* 1 */ claimed_index = 2; m_wr_ptr = 3;
/* 2 */ claimed_offset = 2;
/* 3 */ claimed_data = m_data[2];
/* 4 */ claimed_data.store(t);
/* 5 */ m_size = 1;
```

After:

```
m_size == 1
m_rd_ptr == 1
m_wr_ptr == 3
m_data[1] == 0xDEADBEAF
m_data[2] == value_produced_by_B
```

The consumer now runs, sees `m_size > 0`, and reads from `m_data[1]` while increasing `m_rd_ptr` from 1 to 2.  But `m_data[1]` hasn't been written by Producer A yet, and Producer B wrote to `m_data[2]`.

The second bug is the complementary case in `pop()` when a consumer thread is interrupted between the `m_rd_ptr++` action and the `.load()` call.  It can result in reading values out of order, potentially so far out of order that the queue has completely circled and overwritten the original value.

Just because two operations in a single source statement are atomic does not make the entire statement atomic.

Comment: You don't need threads to sleep for this global ordering of operations.  I'd assume the OP is using an SMP system where the operations of two threads running at the same time can interleave this way.  (BTW, I think for `reserved_index` you meant to write `claimed_index` again.)  Also, operations `/*2*/` and `/*3*/` aren't globally observable at all (they don't read or write any shared variables), it's just what a thread does privately.  Anyway yes, the bug is that `m_size++` doesn't give you an index that's valid to read from because pushes don't have to complete in claim order.

Comment: @PeterCordes: It's true that it isn't necessary for a thread to be preempted, but that is what happens in OP's test run, when the two spawned threads have affinity to the same core.  Thanks for spotting the one leftover use of the variable name that I used while drafting this answer.  Instructions with no global visibility still are important because they increase the window of vulnerability -- timing *IS* a visible side effect when you're talking about multithreading and races.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed the affinity shenanigans.  Since there was already an answer, I skipped down to it to find out what the key part of the long question was about. :P  I guess the OP was hoping that putting both producers on the same core would avoid sequencing problems?  And yeah fair point about more operations -> more latency, but here it's literally 1 extra CPU instruction (`and`) and a base+index addressing mode on x86 or ARM.  (Maybe 1 extra cycle of address-generation latency if stores are like loads on SnB-family).  On a RISC, maybe 1 or 2 extra instructions for address-generation.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Indeed, the first problem described by @Ben Voigt is exactly what is causing the problem.

I was doing the thread affinity "shenanigans" solely because I feared that there was a missing memory fence, which clearly is not the case. As Ben wrote, this problem should also occur on a single-processor system.

I'll have to think about whether the second problem described in the answer is a problem in my specifiy use-case, since the number of elements in the system is limited to the maximum size of the queue.

Comment: @AndreasStöckel: Yes it is a problem even with a limited queue size, because the remaining N-1 items can pass through the queue any number of times before the 1 item is finished processing.  So all array slots can be touched by the other threads, while one thread thinks it has exclusive access.